# Undefined Index when adding a new field to any Content Type or Taxonomy

Tags: 7, entities, media

Every time I add a new field to a taxonomy or any Content type, I get this error message on the edit screen.

[image: Notice: Undefined index: default_image in image_field_update_field() (line 439 of /var/www/html/modules/image/image.module).]
Notice: Undefined index: default_image in image_field_update_field() (line 439 of /var/www/html/modules/image/image.module).

I'm stuck on where to debug next. Drupal logs show this message? Other image related modules include BackgroundField. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your current Drupal version

> A patch to fix this has been committed to 7.x and will be available in
>   7.15. In the meantime, visiting the image field settings form and clicking Save will resolve the issue

More info: http://drupal.org/node/1558548
Patch here: http://drupal.org/files/drupal-1558548-3.patch

Comment: Thank you. I'm still working on a development install for this project. Knowing a fix is coming down is comforting.